# UIButton not changing title in iPhone

Tags: iphone, xcode, uibutton

button is not changing the title. When I first click it changes the title but when I hide the table then it does not show the title on button. I don't know why in `NSLog` it shows title but do not show on button

```
-(IBAction)btnClicked
{
    if (flag==1) 
    {
        flag=0;
        tblSimpleTable.hidden=NO;
        [i setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"UpArrow.png"]];
    }
    else
    {
        flag=1;
        tblSimpleTable.hidden=YES;
        NSLog(@"This is title %@",title);
        btn.titleLabel.text=title;
        [i setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"downArrow.png"]];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

According to the `[UIButton titleLabel]` [reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIButton_Class/UIButton/UIButton.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIButton/titleLabel), that property is *readonly*.

You will need to use `[UIButton setTitle:forState:]` instead.

Apple [reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIButton_Class/UIButton/UIButton.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIButton/setTitle%3aforState%3a).

**EDIT**: Also you can cutdown the size of your implementation:

```
- (IBAction)btnClicked
{
    tblSimpleTable.hidden = flag;
    [i setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:flag ? @"DownArrow.png" : @"UpArrow.png]];
    if (flag)
        [btn setTitle:@title forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    flag = !flag;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try this one

```
[btn setTitle:@"My Title" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Answer (score 1):

Set title of button with its state. In your case your string is **title** then set it like this..

```
[btn setTitle:title forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Answer (score 1):

Try it in this way ..

```
[button setTitle:@"Title" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this...
`[btn setTitle:title forState:UIControlStateNormal]`

According to Apple Documentation of [UIButton](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIButton_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIButton/titleLabel), `titleLabel` is read-only.